# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views ERROR

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Everything works except when it reaches till the last part of the code with "Successfully Registered!" then the error as mentioned in the title appears inside the registerDialog message part.

Anything im doing wrongly? can anyone help me check up my code

Thank you very much.

The app didn't crash though it just exit back to the app main page. and if i press the register button again it will return with the same error.

> private void setRegister(Button b) {
>           b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        private AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task2;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            registerDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this).create();
            registerDialog.setTitle("Register Alert!");
            registerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            registerDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            task2 = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

                ProgressDialog dialog2;
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters2;
                String response2 = null;

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        postParameters2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usernamelog", rUsername.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwordlog", rPassword.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rpasswordlog", rRpassword.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emaillog", rEmail.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumlog", rPhoneNum.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("doblog", rBirthday.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("genderlog", rGender.getText().toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));                 

                        dialog2 = new ProgressDialog(Login.this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                        dialog2.setMessage("Registering...");       

                        dialog2.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        try {
                            response2 = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://whatstherex.info/checkR.php", postParameters2);

                            String res2 = response2.toString();

                            res2 = res2.replaceAll("null", "");

                            if (res2.equals("1")) {
                                res2 = "Successfully Registered!";
                                rAuth.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                                return res2;
                            } else {
                                res2 = res2.toString();
                                rAuth.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                return res2;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            res2 = e.toString();
                            rAuth.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            return res2;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
                        if(!result2.equals("Successfully Registered!") && !result2.equals("Username have to be at least 5 characters") && !result2.equals("Password have to be at least 8 characters") && !result2.equals("Passwords does not match") && !result2.equals("Email field is empty") && !result2.equals("Email field is not valid") && !result2.equals("Phone number Field is empty") && !result2.equals("Phone number is not numeric") && !result2.equals("Phone number is not 8 digit") && !result2.equals("Birthday Field is empty") && !result2.equals("Birthday is not numeric") && !result2.equals("Birthday is not in DDMMYYYY format") && !result2.equals("Gender Field is empty") && !result2.equals("Gender Field is invalid") && !result2.equals("Gender not in the format M or F") && !result2.equals("Duplicate entry '"+rUsername.getText().toString()+"' for key 'username'") && !result2.equals("Duplicate entry '"+rEmail.getText().toString()+"' for key 'email'") && !result2.equals("Duplicate entry '"+rPhoneNum.getText().toString()+"' for key 'phoneNum'")){
                        rAuth.setText("Unknown Error!!!");
                        rAuth.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                        registerDialog.setMessage(result2);
                        registerDialog.show();
                        dialog2.dismiss();
                        }else if (result2.equals("Duplicate entry '"+rUsername.getText().toString()+"' for key 'username'")) {
                            rAuth.setText("Username already in used");
                            rAuth.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            registerDialog.setMessage("Username already in used");
                            registerDialog.show();
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        }else if (result2.equals("Duplicate entry '"+rEmail.getText().toString()+"' for key 'email'")) {
                            rAuth.setText("Email already in used");
                            rAuth.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            registerDialog.setMessage("Email already in used");
                            registerDialog.show();
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        }else if (result2.equals("Duplicate entry '"+rPhoneNum.getText().toString()+"' for key 'phoneNum'")){
                            rAuth.setText("Phone number already in used");
                            rAuth.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            registerDialog.setMessage("Phone number already in used");
                            registerDialog.show();
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        }else {
                            rAuth.setText("Successfully Registered!");
                            rAuth.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            registerDialog.setMessage("Successfully Registered!");
                            registerDialog.show();
                            dialog2.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

            };
            task2.execute();                                    
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: read the stacktrace, you'll find the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that `rAuth` is a `TextView`. This needs to be moved to the `onPostExecute()` as you can't update `UI` elements in the `doInBackground()`. Only the `onPostExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPreExecute()` run on the `UI` thread.

[Here is Link to Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Actually, `onProgressUpdate()` is also on the main application ("UI") thread.

Comment: Yes, thank you @CommonsWare I have updated my answer-forgot about that one until after I posted

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic, i left that part out when adding in the asyncTask. got it up and working now.

Comment: @user1953739 You are most welcome, glad I could help! You may kindly accept the answer if it helped

Comment: just did, got the error to wait for 4 mins :) thanks once again! too much time on coding will just miss the smallest and typical error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't mean to be pushy :) That's true, just have to figure out when to walk away for a bit and hope it doesn't haunt you in your sleep. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You do some UI work in your `doInBackground`, for example this call

```
rAuth.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Move this code to the `onPostExecute` method.